# Что не так в программе?

Tags: c++

Я хочу поделить многочлены с остатком, но при вызове функции delSOstM программа ломается (return -100765...). Наверное ошибка в логике цикла, но я не понимаю, почему. Вроде как я с каждой итерацией уменьшаю количество элементов, рано или поздно он должен прерваться. Код:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath> 
#include <vector> 
using namespace std; 
 
void coutvec (vector <double> f1){ 
for (int i = 0; i < f1.size(); i++){ 
 cout << "f1 " << i << " = " << f1[i]; 
} 
} 
 
 
void delSOstM (vector <double> f1, vector <double> f2){ 
 vector <double> fvsp; 
 int n = 0; 
 while (true){ 
 if (f1.size() < f2.size()) {break;} 
 fvsp[n] = f1[0]/f2[0]; 
 f1.erase(f1.begin()); 
 for (int i = 0; i < f1.size(); i++){ 
 f1[i] = f1[i] - f2[i] * fvsp[n]; 
 } 
 n++; 
 } 
 coutvec (fvsp); 
} 
 
 
 
int main (){ 
 
vector <double> f1 {1.1, 2.3, 3.6, 4.0}; 
vector <double> f2 {1.6, 2.2, 3.8}; 
 
delSOstM (f1, f2); 
return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы просто не выделили память при создании вектора.
Замените эту строку
`vector <double> fvsp;`
на эту
`vector <double> fvsp(f1.size());`